# LibGdx ImageButton playing sound

Tags: libgdx, imagebutton

I have created an imageButton with three drawable images;
one is button-up,button-down and button checked.Its purpose is to ON and OFF sound for the game.once sound is OFF,checked image should be displayed.

I have written the code like this:

```
soundButton = new ImageButton(new TextureRegionDrawable(soundTexture1),
            new TextureRegionDrawable(soundTexture2), new TextureRegionDrawable(soundTexture3));
    stage.addActor(soundButton);

    soundButton.setPosition(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH / 4 + 300f, Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT / 4, Align.bottomLeft);
soundButton.addListener(new ChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            if(!game.soundBool)
                game.soundBool=true;
                else
                    game.soundBool=false;
        }
    });
```

Here soundBool is initially false and game sounds will play when it is false.
once I make it true,sounds should not play.This boolean is working well.

Problem is that once I checked the button(sound OFF) sound is getting OFF permanantly.Again Button click is not working as expected.

How do I change the code to work it well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked how often the `changed()` method is called? Use `Gdx.app.log()` for logging. Or try using a different Listener, like `ClickedListener` for the button.

You could also make you own Button, `class MyButton extends Button` to keep a cleaner code. [Here](https://github.com/reime005/splintersweets/blob/master/core/src/de/reimerm/splintersweets/actors/scene2d/AudioButton.kt) is how I solved it.